# Do NFAs with ϵ-transitions accept languages that no PDA can?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata, pushdown-automata

Is it correct to say that there are languages that a NFA with epsilon recognizes but a PDA is not? I think that it is wrong but I cannot find a suitable explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This follows immediately from the definitions and the basic characterizations of the different kinds of automata.  Every NFA, with or without $\epsilon$-transitions, recognizes a regular language. Every regular language is context-free.  Every context-free language is recognized by a PDA.

Comment: Thank you did not expect something that simple.